# insert "\" symbol in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

```
INSERT INTO `abc`(`info`) VALUES ('\');
```

it's possible mysql database in insert "\" symbol? i try was Collation type change UTF-8 General_ci but not work, any other idea

Comment: Use prepared statements within PHP those functions should escape qoutes and backslash characters automatically and other characters that also needs to be escaped.. And it also protects you against SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
INSERT INTO `abc`(`info`) VALUES ('\\');
```

Comment: get error: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.       `ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 31
STR: '
SQL: 
INSERT INTO abc(info) VALUES ('\');`

Comment: are you use double **\\\**??

Comment: See my answer there is double \\. Use it not single \?

Comment: @GhoriTrilochan verified this answer [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bce6/1) its working

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid your link is very useful. Thanks

Comment: @GhoriTrilochan As I know it is not possible

Comment: This post must be helpful [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)

Answer (score 0):

some step fellow:

1. string replace using "str_replace" function
2. fire insert query...

```html
<?php 
.... 
$abc = $_POST['info'];;

$aa = str_replace("\\",'\\\\',$abc);

$insert = "INSERT INTO `abc`(`info`) VALUES ('$aa')";
?>
```

Comment: **$abc = 'lojjj\uj';

$aa = str_replace("\\",'\\\\',$abc);** this is same ***$abc = 'lojjj\\uj'** why **str_replace** @GhoriTrilochan??

Comment: this value insert by user so i was first store variable than all "\" place replace by "\\"

Comment: and i got this idea your share link so thax for share link .. :)

Comment: Use prepared statements within PHP those functions should escape qoutes and backslash characters automatically and other characters that also needs to be escaped.. And it also protects you against SQL injections..